# How to do servlet authentication against Liferay portal DB?

Tags: authentication, liferay, liferay-6

Currently we are having a servlet application which is getting authenticated against the Jboss portal.But now we are forced to move to Liferay portal from Jboss portal, we need to find the way to authenticate against Liferay portal Database from my servlet application.Currently in my servlet application , I am using webauthentication class to authenticate against Jboss portal.But in liferay I am not finding any custom class which is responsible for doing the servlet authentication. So do I need to write my custom login module ? Anybody please share me if u have any idea/reference on servlet Liferay authentication

Any help is appreciated..

Regards,

Suresh

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter` specifically at `getLoginRemoteUser` method.

Also take a look at classes in `com.liferay.portal.security.auth` package.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [virtual LDAP](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15186785) plugin for Liferay, offering the Liferay user database through the LDAP protocol. Caveat: It seems to be "enterprise edition" only.